# A good example of custom log4net appender outputting text directly to a asp.net control ( custom control , Label , etc)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, log4net

I do have db appender and know how to get the output to a custom "logging" page ... The idea is to have a quick and dirty switch to write for example to the Response object ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really sounds like a dirty hack but you could get away with it using a MemoryAppender. Here's some sample code on how to get to the log data:

```
var memoryAppender = (MemoryAppender)LogManager.GetRepository()
    .GetAppenders().Single(x => x.Name == appenderName);

var events = memoryAppender.GetEvents();
```

After picking the latest events from the appender for rendering you should probably do a

```
memoryAppender.Clear();
```